# custom axis labels plotting a forecast in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I'm trying to get some sensible labels on a forecast.

Here's my code:

```
library("forecast")

t <- ts(
  c(
    4410.0, 6435.0, 
    4939.0, 6487.0, 25521.0, 18764.0, 
    12223.0, 18590.0, 36898.0, 28826.0, 
    20329.0
    )  
  , frequency = 4
  , start=c(2011, 7, 1)
)

cast <- meanf(t,h=4)

par(mfrow=c(1,1),xaxt="n")
plot(cast)

ticks <- seq(as.POSIXct("2011-07-01"), by = "3 month", length.out=length(cast) + 4) 
axis.Date(1, at = ticks, labels = ticks, format="%Y-%m")
```

There are no errors or warnings... but no axis gets added to the plot :(

If I use `xaxt="s"` then I do get axis labels, but they're not they're things like 2014.0 (i.e. not formatted as dates at all). Ideally I'd actually like something a bit more readable like "Q3 2014" but I'd settle for 2014-07 (the first month in the quarter).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? All of the stuff I've found searching the internet suggests disabling the default axis and then using the axis or axis.Date functions to add a custom on... but I can't get an axis of any sort using either of those methods :(

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you do `plot(hw(USAccDeaths,h=48))`, which comes straight from [the help page to `plot.forecast`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/plot.forecast), you don't get the time axis annotated, either. I'd say this qualifies as a bug. I'll point Rob Hyndman to this.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa If I do `require(forecast); plot(hw(USAccDeaths,h=48))` I see labels in the time axis. Maybe you didn't reset the graphical parameters and still had the configuration `par(mfrow=c(1,1),xaxt="n")` from the example given in the question (that happened to me).

Answer (score 1):

I would not say there is a bug, rather the function `forecast::plot.forecast` is not designed to be used with `axis.Date` or `axis.POSIXct` (which are not used in the package `forecast`).

Before calling the functions `axis.Date` and `axis.POSIXct`, the time points must be explicitly passed to `plot` as a sequence of `Date` or `POSIXct` objects. If we plot the time series as `plot(t)` then the x-axis does not seem to be properly defined as to be used by the above functions.

See the code below and how the variable `time` is created and passed to `plot`. `plot(time, x)` is used instead of just `plot(x)`. Thus the function `axis` will be able to display the labels of the time axis. (In this example, the confidence intervals will not look as nice as those 
displayed by `forecast::plot.forecast`.)

```
library("forecast")
require(zoo)

t <- ts(
  c(
    4410.0, 6435.0, 
    4939.0, 6487.0, 25521.0, 18764.0, 
    12223.0, 18590.0, 36898.0, 28826.0, 
    20329.0
    )  
  , frequency = 4
  , start=c(2011, 7, 1)
)
cast <- meanf(t, h=4)

x <- ts(c(t, cast$mean), start = c(start(t), 1), frequency = frequency(t))
time <- as.yearqtr(seq(start(x)[1], end(x)[1] + 1, 1/frequency(x)))
time <- time[seq_along(x)]
time <- as.POSIXct(time)
plot(time, x, type = "n", xaxt = "n", ylim = range(c(cast$lower, cast$upper)))
lines(time[seq_along(t)], t)
lines(time[-seq_along(t)], cast$mean, col = "blue")
lines(time[-seq_along(t)], cast$upper[,2], col = "red")
lines(time[-seq_along(t)], cast$lower[,2], col = "red")
ticks <- seq(as.POSIXct("2011-07-01"), by = "3 month", length.out=length(cast) + 4) 
axis(side = 1, at = ticks, labels = ticks)
```